# How to consume a json array in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this entity Immobile:

```
public Integer usableAreas;
public String listingType;
public LocalDate createdAt;
public String listingStatus;
public Long id;
```

When making the request I get about 10,000 data, however as it is a JSON ARRAY I can't use the rest template without having to convert String to immobile, and this takes a lot of work and makes the code ugly, is there another way for me do that?

```
public List<Immobile> getData() {
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(SOURCE_URL, String.class);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
List<Immobile> immobileList = new ArrayList<>(jsonArray.length());
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    immobileList.add(new Immobile(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("usableAreas"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("listingType"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDate("createdAt"),
            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("listingStatus")));
    }
    return immobileList;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried deserialising into a `List<Immobile>` directly? Just let Spring Boot do it for you, and ask for a `List<Immobile>`.

Comment: In the question, add here what have you tried so far and any specific issue in that..

Comment: I added the code now

Comment: Reading your tags and example code I suspect that you want to consume json from an endpoint. I would recommend you try to integrate https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson which is able to do the conversion for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other alternative is to use ObjectMapper  `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`. Mapping to Entity will be done by ObjectMapper itself

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Immobile> list = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<Immobile>>() { });
```

Comment: @GuilhermePetena Can you explain What exactly didn't work?

Comment: Now it's working, I made a mistake, but now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @GuilhermePetena Glad that I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Try Gson library, it's easy to use

```
Type token = new TypeToken<List<Immobile>>() {}.getType();
List<Immobile> immobileList = new Gson().fromJson(response, token);
```